# Best way to limit threads to a DBs while allowing a larger max thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, threadpool

Fairly noob to C#.  I have 12 Oracle DBs, with roughly 10000+ schemas on each.
I want to run a multi-threaded process (say a query or script) across every schema.

If I: `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100,<not really sure what to put here>)`, it's likely that i'll hit DB1 with 100 connections right out of the gate.

I want to spread that load out to a max of 10 threads/connections per DB at a time, but possibility of 100 running overall.  I know I can't have ThreadPool1, Threadpool2, etc.

What's going to be the best way to handle that?

Any insight appreciated!  --Thanks!

Comment: The number of threads in the `ThreadPool` doesn't dictate how much concurrent work you're doing.  Why not create a class for each database and then handle how many concurrent connections are being used there?

Comment: @Zer0 - This is probably the root of my problem.  I don't know how to limit the threads outside the threadpool.  What would keep class DB1 from burning up the allotment?  As i continue to search, i did find this (which i'm reading through now:)
http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling
Maybe I'll have a better understanding here soon.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting to the ThreadPool will cause 100 connections if you 'start' 100 threads loosely, and the threads will start doing work almost instantaneously against your DB.

One way to limit the number of parallel threads doing work is by using Parallel.ForEach or Parallel.For as they provide a ParallelOptions parameter where you can set the max degree of parallelism:

```
Parallel.ForEach<string>(rows, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = batchSize},(row) => { 
     // your code here 
 } );

Parallel.For(0,100, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = batchSize }, i => { 
    //your code here 
});
```

MaxDegreeOfParallelism will limit the concurrent work to the batchSize value, waiting for the batch to complete before starting a new one until completion.

Comment: HRmm.. i will research this further.  Could this potentially slow it down?  If of the 10, one is large, would that batch wait until all 10 are complete before grabbing the next batch?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, until the full batch is not completed you will not start a new one, is like creating manually 10 Tasks and use WaitAll for all them to complete before creating 10 more.